# Condition Statement in 1D array

Tags: c#, for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++)
{
     NextMove = playerPositions[i] + DiceThrow();

     while (RocketInSquare(NextMove) == true)
          playerPositions[i] = NextMove++;

     playerPositions[i] = NextMove;
}
```

I'm having some trouble with this for loop. Is there a way i can make the line :

```
NextMove = playerPositions[i] + DiceThrow();
```

Only run once in the for loop?

Comment: 1. `if (i == 0)` 2. move it out of the loop body

Comment: It should only run once for each iteration of the for loop already.

Comment: out of curiosity, whats with the parenthesis around the statement in question?

Comment: You mean the curly braces around the assignment of NextMove?, that was what was left of me experimenting, forgot to take them out. Cheers for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should just move that line out of the loop.

```
NextMove = playerPositions[0] + DiceThrow(); 
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++)
{
     while (RocketInSquare(NextMove))
          NextMove++;

     playerPositions[i] = NextMove;
}
```

Comment: Just make sure the array isn't of size 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can include a `flag` or `counter` in combination with an `if` block.

```
if (counter == 0)
{
    NextMove = playerPositions[i] + DiceThrow();
    counter++;
}
```

An alternative approach with `firstIteration` (`bool firstIteration`),

```
firstIteration = false; 

....

for (...)
{
    if (firstIteration)
    {
        NextMove = playerPositions[i] + DiceThrow();
        firstIteration = !firstIteration; // Toggle the flag 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that's brilliant. I just thought of this a couple minutes ago. Thank-you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

Keep a flag

```
    bool flag = false;    
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++)
    {
    if(!flag)
    {
        NextMove = playerPositions[i] + DiceThrow();
        flag = true;  
    } 

    while (RocketInSquare(NextMove) == true)
        {
            playerPositions[i] = NextMove++;

        }
        playerPositions[i] = NextMove;

    }
```